# JS Audio Not Working

Tags: javascript, audio, cpanel, file-manager

One of the sound files won't play. The two following pieces of code are identical except for the file name.

This doesn't work:

```
var rewardSound = new Audio("audio/WrongAnswerSound.wav");
function rightAnswer(){
    rewardSound.play();
}
```

However this works fine:

```
var rewardSound = new Audio("audio/CorrectAnswerSound.wav");
function rightAnswer(){
    rewardSound.play();
}
```

The image is from the File Manager in cPanel. I can play both sounds from the File Manager itself. But, I cann't play the WrongAnswerSound.wav from the JS code. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Snippet showing the two files]

Comment: What if you rename it ... change the word "Wrong" to something else?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the two sounds with two links?

Answer (score 2):

You kind of have the right idea.

Set a variable for the correct sound by creating a new Audio object:

`var correctSound = new Audio("audio/CorrectAnswerSound.wav");`

Set a variable for the wrong sound by creating another new Audio object:

`var wrongSound = new Audio("audio/WrongAnswerSound.wav");`

Now you both of these new objects already hold a play method that they get from the Audio object. So all you have to do to get these sounds to play is this:

`correctSound.play();
wrongSound.play();`